# How can i get the data that contain the max value without duplicate and with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

How can i get rows of the last "datetime" added for each user depends on group id, then from that results find the max "right_answers" from all users and finally if two user equal then get the low "timesec" value

```
Data table:
- - - - - - -
Groupid | Name | date_time              | right_answers | timesec
  1     | Fadi | 2020-11-24 11:04:00    |   1           |   10  
  1     | Jake | 2020-11-24 11:14:00    |   9           |   70
  1     | Fadi | 2020-11-24 11:24:00    |   5           |   40
  1     | Jake | 2020-11-24 11:34:00    |   7           |   50
  1     | Jake | 2020-11-24 11:54:00    |   5           |   35
  2     | Bob  | 2020-11-24 11:59:00    |   8           |   45

Desired result:
- - - - - - - - -
Name | date_time            | right_answers | timesec
Jake | 2020-11-24 11:30:00  |   5           |   35  
Fadi | 2020-11-24 11:54:00  |   5           |   40
```

the result depends on:

- the last date time added (no matter what the count of the right answers is)
- the max right answers
- if equal with other user then order by timesec

**timesec** = time in seconds for resolving the puzzle

I tried like this but, it's give me the first datetime:

```
$Sql = "SELECT users.firstname, users.fathername, users.lastname, 
scores.user_id,scores.right_answers,scores.timesec, scores.user_id 
FROM scores 
INNER JOIN users ON scores.user_id=users.id
WHERE scores.group_id='$groupID' 
GROUP BY scores.user_id
ORDER BY scores.date_time ASC, scores.right_answers DESC, scores.timesec ASC";
```

in this case: I've got the resutl with names repeating (like fadi repeats 3 times and Jake 3 times)

```
$Sql = "SELECT users.firstname, users.fathername, users.lastname,    
scores.user_id,scores.right_answers,scores.timesec, scores.user_id 
FROM scores 
INNER JOIN users ON scores.user_id=users.id
WHERE scores.group_id='$groupID' 
ORDER BY scores.right_answers DESC, scores.timesec ASC";
```

Thank you ...

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: I used this command: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"     

10.4.13-MariaDB